# Como hacer funcionar el botón cambiar idioma en un pagina HTML estática - Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Compré una plantilla en Envytheme, tiene un boton para cambiar idioma, pero no encuentro como hacerlo funcionar, me recomendaron crear archivos separadas, es decir un index en español y otro en inglés y así lo hice, pero aun no encuentro el modo de hacer que lo lea. También intenté cambiar las letras "Eng" y "Esp" por las banderas de los respectivos idiomas, pero tampoco pude. Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="option-inner">
    <div class="others-options d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="option-item">
        <div class="languages-list">
          <select>
            <option value="1">Span</option>
            <option value="2">Eng</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Las etiquetas de `<select>` y `<option>` no creo que resuelvan lo que quieras realizar.
Lo que puedes utilizar son las etiquetas `<ul>`, `<li>` y `<a>`.
En ese caso, si podrías crear un archivo en inglés y otro en español, debes crear con la etiqueta `<ul>` una lista desordena y con la etiqueta `<li>` define un elemento de lista, luego, con la etiqueta `<a>` puedes ingresarle el link de la ruta donde se encuentran el archivo y con estilado puedes realizar un dropdown para crear esa sensación de que estás eligiendo entre dos opciones.

Te dejo un ejemplo que te va a servir para entender lo que te explico:

**HTML & CSS Styles**

```css
    ul li {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-left: 2px solid #3ca0e7;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 30px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: arvo;
    }

    li a {
      color: black;
    }

    li a:hover {
      color: #3ca0e7;
    }

    li:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul li ul {
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: none;
      background: white;
    }

    ul li:hover > ul,
    ul li ul:hover {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      min-width: 250px;
      text-align: left;
      padding-top: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px #ccc;
    }

    ul li ul li {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-style: none;
    }

    ul li ul li a:hover {
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-left: 2px solid #3ca0e7;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }


a {

    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover {
        color: #3CA0E7;
    }
 
}

 ul li ul li a { transition: all 0.5s ease; }
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="primary-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Language &dtrif;</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="./Spanish.html">Spanish</a></li>
        <li><a href="./English.html">English</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```